# The provided key element does not match the schema - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

> **I have seen a similar question posted on stackoverflow but the answers weren't able to work to solve my issue**

I have created a resource in my API GETWAY of type `GET`. In my Query strings I'm passing the follwing:

```
email=x@gmail.com
```

or

```
racf=XXXX&email=x@gmail.com
```

**I get this error:**

> The provided key element does not match the schema

But if I do it with the primary key, it works.

```
racf=XXXX
```

**I have created an index in dynamoDB for the email attribute**

**LAMBDA FUNCION:**

```
case 'GET':
    if (event.queryStringParameters) {
      dynamo.getItem({ 
          TableName: "eventregistration-db",
          Key:{
            //"racf": event.queryStringParameters.racf,
            "email": event.queryStringParameters.email
          }
       },done);
   } else {
     dynamo.scan({ TableName: tableName }, done);  
  }               
 break;
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `%40` for the `@` sign?  The `@` sign can indicate other things in a URL.

Comment: ohh no I see what you are saying since it's a special character. I'' try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `email` is not a part of your [Primary Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html) of the DynamoDb table.

For [`getItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property) you have to use table columns the table's primary key (partition key and optionally sort key) is composed from.

`scan` doesn't need any key, because it makes a full search on the table - that's why it works in that case.

Set `email` (and `racf`) as table's primary key to make it work with .

**If you want to use an index**, you have to use [`query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property):

```
dynamo.query({
    TableName: tableName,
    IndexName: indexName,
    KeyConditionExpression: "email = :email",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":email": event.queryStringParameters.email
    }
}, done);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to follow your example (which I have tried that too), but it gives me the following error: `The table does not have the specified index: email-index` Under the dynamoDB i see my index name being email-index.

Comment: had emai-index instead of email. Thank you sir!

Comment: Question, everytime I want to do a query I have to use an index, correct? is there an other way to query or search an item that doesn't have an index?

Comment: If you want to use an index, you have to use `query`, but you can use `getItem` to get an item by the primary key, or `scan` for the full search without any key or index.